# Sphere submerged in a thin layer of gel (fluid with yield stress) that is spread on a vertical wall

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, viscosity

Imagine a uniform thin layer of a viscous gel sticking on a vertical wall. A small sphere is submerged in this gel. The gel has a yield stress (Bingham model). How can I calculate the yield stress that will cause the sphere to start sliding with the fluid on the wall? This yield stress will obviously depend on the weight and dimensions of the sphere.

Comment: Can you please provide a sketch?

Comment: When you say “sliding with the fluid,” do you mean the sphere and fluid are sliding together? Or that the sphere moves through the motionless fluid? Or something else?

Comment: I do not know which failure mechanism will happen sooner. The sphere could start moving in the fluid, or the fluid and the sphere could slide together. Here is a sketch of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MM5R9dX1aQ9nfd6z8XIzy9xnZQ4tT2OR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your mechanics background? Are you familiar with [free-body diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body_diagram)?

Comment: Yes. I have a civil engineering background. I also have an experimental soft matter background. I will understand partial differential equations for fluid dynamics.

Comment: To estimate whether the gel will slip, use a free-body diagram to calculate the shear stress at the interface, and compare it to the yield shear stress. To investigate the stress field around the sphere and its possible motion, consider reviewing Beris et al.'s "[Creeping motion of a sphere through a Bingham plastic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/abs/creeping-motion-of-a-sphere-through-a-bingham-plastic/58DA7E990C0D389D714EC311337CB0E0)," its references, and the papers citing it.